# iPhoto: How to only set the year of a picture?

Tags: photos.app

I use iPhoto to manage my pictures. Unfortunately I have many pictures from the 80s. These pictures are actually slides that I have scanned in during 2008. So my problem is that the creation date of all these pictures is set to the date when I scanned it in. Now I want to set the real date of these pictures. Unfortunately I don't know the exact date, but at least the year.

So is there any function available to only set the year field of a date without a specific date?

Comment: Unless I can identify a more accurate date, I generally set these photos to January 1 of the appropriate year initially. Later on I may refine them: July 1 (if it's a summer scene), October 31 (Halloween costumes), etc. A keyword such as ***?date*** will help you to identify (and refine) such pictures.

Comment: That would be my less-than-ideal-solution. But I would prefer if it is somehow possible to set these ?date or ? directly in the metadates of the picture.

Comment: You can do that. Your question specifically asked for a way to set **only** the year.

Comment: So how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the photos you want to set a date for. In the menu, select **Photos > Batch Change**, then select date from the dialog pop-up.

Comment: Thanks. I already saw that, but I want to set something like unknown or ? or something similar to the day and month field and only add a real year.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my original comment. You can't do that, which is why I default to "Jan 1", or the nearest identifiable date, and use a keyword. Less than ideal, but it serves.